# Syncing seconday user store in WSO2 Identity Server cluster

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have setup the cluster for WSO2-IS (2 instances on different machines) based on the information provided here - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/WSO2+Clustering+and+Deployment+Guide

1. Setup DB with a user store, shared registry, 2 local registries
2. Copied the DB driver jar to component lib
3. Updated the master-datasource.xml
4. Updated the registry.xml (made sure the master is read-only false and worker is read-only true)
5. Updated the AXIS2.xml and used WKA for membership scheme
6. Performed other changes as suggested in the link
7. Started the master with -Dsetup option and the worker without -Dsetup option.
8. Verified that the governance folder is shown as a symlink

I can see the interaction between both the nodes, there are Hazelcast messages related to node joining when the worker is started.

User created in 1 is able to login to the other instance, service provider are also automatically available when viewed through UI.

The problem is that when I create a secondary user store (JDBC) in the first node and goto the list in the second node - the secondary user store is not present and I cannot view the users in the user list too.

Am I missing something or is it the way the cluster is supposed to perform i.e. secondary user stores have to be shared in some other way?

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Secondary user store configurations are not synced between two nodes by default. Once you create a secondary user store from UI, it will create a file in following location.
[WSO2_IS]/repository/deployment/server/userstores/ 
These configuration file need to copy by manually or have to use some synchronization mechanism to copy file to other node. since this is not a frequent task better to copy this file.

Fore more information 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores